# Send transaction in the backend on behalf of another person

Tags: dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am designing like platform service. The user (browser) will send a web request to a backend server. The backend server will send transaction with platform's wallet, for the user. The user does not require to initiate / sign the transaction with his user wallet.

The user requests from different user will be queued / processed in the backend server. If one request is pending for one minute; will be considered timeout, and the server will send a cancellation request. And, then process the next one.

Do you think this is a reasonable design? Or any alternative solution?

Comment: Anything that user do not requires to sign a transaction is not possible without the user share his/her private key. And it is not a good approach.

Comment: The user does not require sign transaction. The platform sign the transcation wtih platform wallet. The user does not send the private key to backend. The user treats this like a web2 application. What do you think? @ofarukcaki

Comment: Then it's reasonable. This is the same approach how centralized exchanges processes user withdrawals for example.